# Is it possible to create an object that is @RooSolrSearchable without being a JPA entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo, solrj

Is it possible to create an object that is @RooSolrSearchable without being a JPA entity?

We have an object model made up of 5-6 layers of composition. We need to search on some text fields in the lowest level of the object model, but we need to filter by the upper layers. Our thought was to create a DTO specifically for Solr, that way we can run filterqueries on the ID fields, and fuzzy matches on the text fields.

Roo expects a little different model... if you annotate an object as @RooSolrSearchable, it expects it to be a JPA entity. We just want search, and the benefits of using search (Aspect generation, etc) without it being an JPA entity. We could of course, do this the manual way with Spring and SolrJ... but we'd rather have Roo do the hard work.

What's the best way for us to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there really isn't a way to do this that I can find. We ended up using the normal Solr-Spring integration (which isn't all that bad).